# Generating PHP file to cache XML data

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently developing a Web application with `Zend Framework` and `PHP 5.3`. I have a `XML` file that contain configs and mapping information (+- 1500 lines). On each request I perform an `xpath` query to get information from that `XML` file. The information that is found in the `XML` file is static and do not change after the deployment of the application.

It is a good practice to generated a php file that contain the `XML` information in a static arrays on the first request and then load that php file on every request to get the information instead of doing queries on the `XML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the parsed config file as source file with var_export.

Generating code to cache resources is implemented in several places in Zend Framework, for example autoloader, so I presume it is good practice.

There is also another way to cache it - with serialize (make sure to serialize an array, not for example a SimpleXML object) or Zend_Cache which does more or less the same but is more flexible as to how the result is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Since the XML not changes after deploy, i think it would be the best to transform that XML in your local dev env, and not on the productive system when needed. Its not a good idea to generate source on the productive system that will be automatically included without any validation.

I'm not very familiar with XSLT, but it might be an option for you, according to the concrete structure of that XML.

Comment: thank you for your response, what i was looking to do is something like the php dumper in symfony 2, they used it to cache the DI container configurations. [Symfony Service Container](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/16/symfony-service-container-the-need-for-speed). I was just wondering if it's a good practice to do it and what's the best practice in PHP to cache medium size static file to avoid to parsed it on every request